# How to save mailmerged document into a template?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

Hi I am quite new to this VBA programming, I would really appreciate your help. All I want to do is to save the mail merged document in to a template.

I am using **ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate** property which doesn't seems to work.
Snippet of code below. PLEASE HELP. I am able to mailmerge documents correctly.

```
                ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "C:\Users\xx\Dev\Letterhead.docx"
                With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
                    .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
                End With

                .Execute Pause:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "save as a Word template", and you mean a real Word template (.dotx or .dotm) then what you need after the .Execute is something like the following. If you mean something else, please clarify your question.

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "the full path name of the .dotx", wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLTemplate
```

or

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "the full path name of the .dotm", wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
```

If you mean "save as a .docx", then it would be

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 "the full path name of the .docx", wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument
```

You may be surprised that this uses ActiveDocument, but the fact is that when the merge is complete, the Output document becomes the ActiveDocument. SO it is usually a good idea to make a reference to the ActiveDocument before you merge, e.g.

```
Dim mmmd As Word.Document
Set mmmd = ActiveDocument
With mmmd.MailMerge
'...
  .Execute Pause:=False

' At this point you can use the mmmd object reference 
' to do something to the mail merge main Document, 
' and ActiveDocument to manipulate the output

End With
Set mmmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am mail merging documents. I have got a company letterhead template. I am mail merging them correctly and saving them as a pdf without any issue. All I need to do now is to attach a company letterhead template to it before saving them.
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat actPath & FNMTobeSavedAs & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF is the command I am using to save the document as PDF.

Comment: The output I am working for is when I will open the saved document after mailmerge, it should open in the company letterhead with all mailmerged content in it. Hope it make sense.

Comment: In that case you would need to attach the template to the ActiveDocument _after_ each merge, but I am not sure that that is what you really need, because attaching a template after a document has been created does not change the document. If you need to _insert_ a letterhead, you either need to modify the mail merge main document o include the letter head in the first place, or (perhaps) use InsertFile to insert the file at the beginning of each output file. Or is it something else?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was on my annual leave and that is the reason for late reply. You got it exactly right bibadia I need to attach a letterhead after each merge before saving it as a PDF. I will try InsertFile option and will update.